# Excel renaming buttons after save

Tags: excel, vba

After ctrl+S excel renames buttons for unknown reasons.
The buttons are created by vba code.
When I right click on the button and then release mouse it will show "Button XX" name. However if I right click on the button and hold mouse button it will show the old name.
Is this a common bug?

```
Sub ButtonAdd(ByRef RangeTarget As Range, Optional ByVal WidthOffset As Variant, Optional ByVal HeightOffset As Variant, Optional ByVal Width As Variant, Optional ByVal Height As Variant, Optional Name As Variant = "Button", Optional Caption As Variant = "Button", Optional Command As Variant)
    If IsMissing(WidthOffset) = True Then WidthOffset = 0
    If IsMissing(HeightOffset) = True Then HeightOffset = 0
    With ASheet.Buttons.Add(RangeTarget.Left + WidthOffset, RangeTarget.Top + HeightOffset, RangeTarget.Width, RangeTarget.Height)
        .Name = Name
        .Caption = Caption
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .AutoScaleFont = True
        If IsMissing(Width) = False Then .Width = Width Else .Width = .Width - 2 * WidthOffset
        If IsMissing(Height) = False Then .Height = Height Else .Height = .Height - 2 * HeightOffset
        .OnAction = Command
    End With
End Sub
```

**Sample Screenshot below:** 
http://shrani.si/f/3A/Az/4bKcrnk6/capture.jpg

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Ok I've also tried this:

```
Sub ch()
    Dim z As Shape
    For Each z In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            MsgBox z.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

And it shows bunch of buttons that aren't on the sheet (even ctrl+A +delete) apparenetly doesn't remove them.

Comment: It appears that this thing can only happen if there are duplicates with the same name. And after saving it will rename one of the buttons. So I assume my script is making some hidden buttons.

Comment: can you add a screenshot with the button?

Comment: The button is over multiple cells. And basically I added msgbox into the only subroutine that adds button and it's added only once. So for some reason excel is thinking that the button already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have multiple buttons stacked on each other and when you save and then reselect the button you are actually selecting the top button which could not be renamed because the name was taken.

Using `RangeTarget.Parent` instead of `ASheet` will make your code more versatile.

```
With RangeTarget.Parent.Buttons.Add(RangeTarget.Left + WidthOffset, RangeTarget.Top + HeightOffset, RangeTarget.Width, RangeTarget.Height)
```

Comment: Nope. All buttons are literally nowhere on the sheet. If I do .topleftcell.address on them they are all on $A$1. It's excel bug most likely.

Comment: Good tip on using .parent on ranges. :)

Comment: Well after polishing the code I think the problem solved itself. There might have been some cyclic range sets that probably generated invisible buttons. Although if the problem appears again I'll post the workbook.